# Converting a vector with continuous and categorical values into a vector of factors

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector that contains values between 0 and 12 (continuous) representing age, and also 2 token values 97 and 99 that indicate "did not answer" and "missing" respectively, so something like:

```
v <- sample(c(sample(1:12, 95, replace = TRUE), 99, 99, 97, 99, 99))
```

I want to convert this numeric vector to a vector of factors, where I discretize the continuous values between 1 and 12 into three equal-interval bins (i.e. `[1,4), [4, 8), [8,12]`), so that in the end I have a vector of factors with 5 levels, three for the bins, and 2 for `97` and `99`. I am trying to find the best/most efficient way to do this very generally in R.

**Update**

To put it in more concrete terms, I want a function `numeric2factor` that accepts a vector of values `vec`, a vector of tokens `tokens`, the range of the continuous values specified by `start` and `end`, and a discretization function `discrFunc`. `numeric2factor` converts `vec = v` from the example above into a vector of factors.

Assume that `end` is less than the lowest token values (for example, `end=12` and the lowest token value is something like 97), so there is no overlap between continuous and categorical values.

`discrFunc` does something like return the cut-points (according to some discretization method) of just the continuous values from `vec`.

Comment: Try with `cut` i.e. `cut(v, breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 8, 12, Inf))`

Comment: I would do `cut(v, breaks = c(0,4,8,13,97:100), right = FALSE)` - you can set the labels for the groups to be whatever you want as well but that will break them up the way you want.

Comment: I'm looking for something more generic than that. Let's say I want a function `numeric2factor` that accepts a vector `v`, another vector `tokens` containing only the token values, and a function `discrFunc` that figures out how to discretize a range of continuous values and returns the cutpoints. The function `numeric2factor` will return the vector of factors. Even pseudocode would be useful, I'm not looking for a full-fledged implementation.

Comment: What happens to 98? or 100? And how do you know the difference between age of 99 and code 99 for missing?

Comment: Is it acceptable to start with `is.na(v) <- v == 99`? It makes more sense.

Comment: Hmm, how about `numeric2factor` also accepts two values specifying the `start` and `end` of the continuous values. `end` is much less than the lowest token value, so the values don't overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the start, might need to adapt to your specific needs:

```
set.seed(1);v <- sample(c(sample(1:12, 95, replace = TRUE), 99, 99, 97, 99, 99))
table(v)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 97 99 
# 5  6  9  7 13 10  4  8  8 11 10  4  1  4 

numeric2factor <- function(x, start, end, bins){
  res <- character(length = length(x))
  ix1 <- x >= start & x <= end
  res[ ix1 ] <- as.character(cut(x[ ix1 ], seq(min(x[ ix1 ]) - 1, max(x[ ix1 ]),
                                               length.out = bins + 1)))
  res[ !ix1 ] <- x[ !ix1 ]
  as.factor(res)

}

table(numeric2factor(v, min(v), 12, 3))
# (0,4]  (4,8] (8,12]     97     99 
#    27     35     33      1      4
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful.